# Javascript setHours(1) not working for Mar 27 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100

Tags: javascript, date

I'm totally confused as of why this is not working?

I'm iterating through a date range and just add 1 hour step by step. This worked fine until this week. Basically until the date hits Mar 27 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100. Then it just stucks and does not add anything. If I add +3h then it works again, but not with +1.

I'm using Firebug on Firefox and also tried it in the console.

```
Sun Mar 27 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100

>>> this.setHours(0);
1301180400000
>>> this.setHours(1);
1301184000000
>>> this.setHours(2);
1301184000000
>>> this.setHours(3);
1301187600000
```

This is the code:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
    this.setHours(this.getHours() + h);
    return this;
}
```

I have the same bug in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daylight Saving Time causing this behavior.
27 March is the day DST starts.

Edit:

Hope this solves your problem: [Daylight Saving in JavaScript](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltime4.htm)

Comment: Sometimes it's referred to as "summer time". The date things switch varies country by country (or sometimes at even finer levels of political granularity).

Comment: Aha, ok. And what do I do about this? I would like to keep my increment counter if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I guess I could check for daylight saving in every loop. But was hoping to find something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: Could it be related to Daylight Savings time?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but just in case someone else hits this problem, using UTC methods you can avoid this behaviour:

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
    this.setUTCHours(this.getUTCHours() + h);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem as you and resolved it with

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
    this = new Date(this.getTime() + h*3600000);
    return this;
}
```

I'm not sure if creating a new Date object is a good idea but it works for me.